# How to fix broken images in gallery?

Tags: gallery, images, files

I am using Celkon Q54+ running Android 4.4. When I copy some JPEG images from my computer to my phone via USB Storage mode, those images are displayed as broken images in the Gallery app.

I have tried clearing the data for the Gallery app. I have also tried installing third party Gallery Apps like QuickPic from the Play Store. No app seems to detect my photos. But the photos are looking fine when opened from my computer.

How to fix this?

Edit: Only HD images shot with DSLR cameras are not showing up in gallery. They have resolutions of the order of 5000 pixels. Images of resolution less than or equal to 1600x1200 are perfectly displayed in Gallery.